# skip all Umbraco magic for single method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I was just assigned to implement one functionality in project that uses Umbraco. My job is to basically generate specific XML and return it to user. However i cannot get it to work, because when i create new controller (i've tried creating

```
Controller, RenderMvcController and SurfaceController
```

) and method in it (also if i just create new method in existing controller), i get error 404 after typing url into browser. Example: I create **TestController** and method **Index** in it. I've tried combinations where TestController was derived from RenderMvcController or SurfaceController or just Controller. After compiling, etc. when i run

```
http://my_address/Test
```

or

```
http://my_address/Test/Index
```

i get 404 error from umbraco. I looked at another pages in umbraco that were already in project and they all are also configured somehow in umbraco web panel:

```
http://my_address/umbraco
```

I aslo tried adding new methods to existings controllers, but no luck (again 404 errors). I've never worked with umbraco and i don't know how to configure it. I just want to know if there is any way to create method which will be accessible at:

```
http://my_address/MyMethod
```

or

```
http://my_address/MyController/MyMethod
```

and would return just exactly what i will program it to (without any Views, Partial Views, etc. - i can set Headers and ContentType manually and my content is pure text) in an existing Umbraco project without having to deal with umbraco admin panel?

Thanks for any help :)

//Edit

My mind is officially blown... My response is culture dependent (i mean i pull different data from db depending on country), but it's not as simple as

```
CurrentCulture.CultureInfo
```

Umbraco is configured to return different culture based on domain extension (Germany for .de, Great Britain for .co.uk, and Dennmark for .dk - it's just a manual configuration in umbraco admin panel assigning different culture info and views to different hostnames). Regular controllers get this modified culture from

```
RenderModel.CurrentCulture
```

passed as argument to controller's method. Is there a way to create umbraco controller/method/anthing that will not have layout/model assigned to it (so i can display pure XML data i receive from external service) and still have access to umbraco's RenderModel's culture? What i am trying to create is if user types url:

```
http://my_address.de/myController/myMethod
```

my controller will get current culture, call external service passing culture as parameter and display received data without wrapping it in any views. Example:

```
public class myController : SomeBaseUmbracoControllerOrsomething
{
    public string/XmlDocument/ActionResult myMethod(RenderModel model)
    {
        int countryId = myFunctionToTranslateCultureToCountryId(model.CurrentCulture);
        return MethodThatCallsExternalServiceAndReturnsXml(countryId);
    }
}
```

Sorry for confusion, but i've learned about this whole mess with countries just now...

Comment: If you create `SurfaceController` you get to it by typing `http://my_address/umbraco/surface/yourcontroller/youraction`

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use

- **controller**, because this is not picked up by umbraco routing process
- you don't want to use **RenderMvcController**, because this is overkill
- you don't want to use **Surfacecontroller** because you are not using a Child action or form.

What you need is a **UmbracoApiController** (http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/WebApi/) or is your umbraco version is PRE 6.1 then use **/Base extention** (http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Api/Base/Index)

Or if you really want to skip ALL umbraco magic for a certain route, add the path to the web.config/AppSettings/umbracoReservedUrls.